# How do I find the context in which document.write operates. Can you solve the riddle

Tags: document.write

Basically i have these two lines of code written right after each other.:

```
console.log(typeof (noAdsCallback));
document.write('<sc' + 'ript type="text/javascript">console.log(typeof(noAdsCallback));</scr' + 'ipt>');
```

The first one logs `function`, the second logs `undefined`.

Of course it's a bit trickier than that. So here is the set-up in a nutshell:

I have a so called waterfall of ad-providers. That means, I try to load some Ads, by writing (using document.write) some special tags (given to me by my ad-provider).

If the provider doesn't find an ad for me, they send back a javascript-snippet which looks like this:

```
if (typeof(window.noAdsCallback) === "function") noAdsCallback();
```

This function essentially writes the tags of the next provider, which does the same as the first one until I reach the end of the list.

This system actually works fine, doing exactly what I want it to do. Both lines given in the beginning log `function`.

Except if I use Google as an ad-provider. There is one thing Google does differently, which seems to mess everything up.

In Google, I cannot define a fallback-JavaScript-snippet. All I can do is provide a fallback-url. So this fallback-url (since it's loaded inside an iframe inside an iframe inside...) sends a postMessage to the top, which then calls the same noAdsCallback() method. And this too, works just fine. The message is received and the right method executed. However, already the two lines already give different results, i.e. `function` and `undefined` respectively

The next provider then fails to find the noAdsCallback() Method, when it returns, because it uses document.write to try to execute it. Somehow, the context was lost.

**First hint:** It works fine (i.e. both lines log `function`) in Chrome, but it doesn't work in FF or IE.

**Second hint:** It works fine, as long as context never switches, but if communication runs at any point through messaging, it get's confused.

**Third hint:** Using the fantastic postscribe library as mentioned below, actually solves the problem, but introduces new ones somewhere else.

**Fourth hint:** Debugging the window.name, before using document.write, gives the correct name, so I'm not in a random iFrame.

Finishing thoughts. I know, i know: DON'T USE DOCUMENT WRITE!! I know that. But since Adproviders use it all the time, I am forced to use it to, otherwise I get this:

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

In Fact, right now I'm using postscribe (https://github.com/krux/postscribe) and it works like a charm, except for one lousey provider. And the workauround solution would be, to use document.write only for this lousy provider and postscribe for all the others. But i would really like to find out what the root of the problem is.

Any Ideas, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understood it now. Long story short: DON'T USE DOCUMENT.WRITE :)

Try postscribe, if you have to.

So in hindsight it is quite obvious, because really, anywhere you read about document.write() it says, that write() clears the whole document. And I just didn't get it, because I never saw it happening and every ad is using it, like the whole time. Plus, it seemed to work fine on Chrome. So what's going on??

Well here is what happens. As long as the document is open, which basically means while it is being written, document.write() just appends to the stream, and doesn't clear the document. And as long as I used document.write(), to append foreign ad-scripts (which may and will contain document.write()), the page does not close, hence the document stays open.

This is the reason, why adding Google to my waterfall, posed a problem: Google puts everything in iframes. So the page containing the waterfall model just sees the iframe and says: "well as far as I'm concerned, I'm done" and closes the document, while in fact, Google is still at it.

Afterwards, Google didn't find an ad, sends a postMessage to the main page, causing the next provider to be used. Who then uses document.write() and clears everything.

Everything? Not everything. Remember, it still used to work when I used Chrome? The reason for that is, Chrome just clears the HTML but leaves the Javascript intact. So on Chrome, my Javascript-waterfall worked fine, because all the JS-objects where still in place. All other browsers cleared it.

So that's it. Probably noone's gonna read it, but if you do, USE POSTSCRIBE! Now that I finally really understood document.write() and document.open() and document.close() I'm a big fan.